# Android Studio Layout Design editor problem

Tags: android, android-layout, design-patterns

[image: Android Studio layout preview]

Layout design Editor is not responding.  When I drag anything to the design layout it moves to the top left corner and on clicking it disappears.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvand.png)

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="Solid White"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="@string/TextView"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

enter code here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please tell me what to do with this problem

Comment: There's a yellow warning next to your text view - there's a problem that you need to fix. Click the yellow warning in the top right corner, what does the error message say?

Comment: Now i had removed the warning... but the same problem still exists -Michael Dodd

Comment: Can you add your layout XML code [as an edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54809128/edit) **as text** please?

Comment: Now see it plz sir

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54809037/android-studio-design-editor-is-not-responding

Comment: @Fantômas I'd argue the duplicate is the other way round, this question has the more detailed information. Either way, the question you linked to has now been deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use an invalid colour value. On the line:

```
android:textColor="Solid White"
```

`Solid White` is not a valid resource name. You either need to use a hexadecimal value e.g.

```
android:textColor="#ffffff"
```

Or a colour resource e.g.

```
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
```

Comment: Am sorry to say the same problem still exists.

Comment: In which case can you edit your question to include the full contents of your XML file? There may be other errors.

Comment: Now See this my dear Friend